# help with a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

i have a DB with all transactions of my online webshop, and im trying to make a query to print out a simple financial statement.

it will be printed in a table like this:

```
<th>month</th>
<th>number of sales</th>
<th>money in</th>
<th>money out</th>
<th>result</th>
```

the query that fails with: #1111 - Invalid use of group function

```
SELECT 
month(transaction_date) as month,
count(incoming_amount > '0') as number_of_sales,
sum(incoming_amount / 1.25) as money_in,
sum(outgoing_amount) as money_out,
sum((incoming_amount / 1.25) - sum(outgoing_amount)) as result
FROM myDB WHERE year(timestamp) = '2011' order by id desc");
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you really have a table called `myDB` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
month(transaction_date) as month,
sum(if(incoming_amount>0,1,0)) as number_of_sales,
sum(incoming_amount)/1.25 as money_in,
sum(outgoing_amount) as money_out,
sum((incoming_amount/1.25)-outgoing_amount) as result
FROM myDB 
WHERE timestamp>='2011-01-01 00:00:00' AND timestamp<='2011-12-11 23:59:59'
GROUP BY month;
```

1. you need to specify a column when using aggregate function
2. `year(timestamp)` does not make use on mysql index (if you have define an index on timestamp)
3. aggregate function on `count(incoming_amount > '0')` is incorrect
4. `sum` does not looks correct too

Answer (score 1):

Add group by statement:

```
SELECT 
month(transaction_date) as month,
count(incoming_amount > '0') as number_of_sales,
sum(incoming_amount / 1.25) as money_in,
sum(outgoing_amount) as money_out,
sum((incoming_amount / 1.25) - sum(outgoing_amount)) as result
FROM myDB WHERE year(timestamp) = '2011' GROUP BY month order by id desc");
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @ajreal's answer, you can speed this query up by reusing previously calculated values like so:

```
SELECT s.*,
       (s.money_in - s.money_out) as result 
FROM
  (
  SELECT 
    month(transaction_date) as month,
    /*  year(transaction_date) as year   */  
    sum(incoming_amount>0) as number_of_sales, -- true = 1, false = 0.
    sum(incoming_amount)/1.25 as money_in,
    sum(outgoing_amount) as money_out,
  FROM myDB 
  WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN '2011-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-12-31 23:59:59'
  GROUP BY /*year,*/ month DESC;
  ) AS s
```

If you select beyond the year, uncomment the relevant sections.
Note you can add a `DESC` modifier to `group by` to get the most recent results first.